# Search all rows in QTableView using PySide

Tags: python, pyside

How can I filters rows in a QTableView, using a search string that checks every display role's value of each column per row? Keeping in mind in this case the columns which are visible can change based on the Checkboxes. While maintaining the ability to Sort the rows by clicking on the Column headers.

[image]

```
import os, sys, json, pprint
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PS_SITEPACKAGES'))
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class QDictTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QDictTableView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400,300)

        # controls
        self.ui_search_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ui_search_input.setPlaceholderText('Search...')

        self.ui_name_filter = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Name')
        self.ui_age_filter = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Age')
        self.ui_career_filter = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Career')

        self.ui_item_table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.ui_item_table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_item_table.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_item_table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.ui_item_table.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())

        # lay main
        lay_filters = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay_filters.addWidget(self.ui_name_filter)
        lay_filters.addWidget(self.ui_age_filter)
        lay_filters.addWidget(self.ui_career_filter)

        lay_main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay_main.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_search_input)
        lay_main.addLayout(lay_filters)
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_item_table)
        self.setLayout(lay_main)

        # connections
        self.ui_search_input.textChanged.connect(self.changed_text)
        self.ui_name_filter.stateChanged.connect(self.populate_table)
        self.ui_age_filter.stateChanged.connect(self.populate_table)
        self.ui_career_filter.stateChanged.connect(self.populate_table)

        # being
        self.populate_table()
        self.ui_name_filter.setChecked(True)
        self.ui_age_filter.setChecked(True)
        self.ui_career_filter.setChecked(True)


    # methods
    def changed_text(self, text):
        print 'SEARCHING:', text


    def populate_table(self):
        people = [
            {'name': 'Kevin', 'age': 5, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'Maggie', 'age': 13, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Leslie', 'age': 32, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Emily', 'age': 45, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'David', 'age': 27, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 63, 'career': 'secretary'}
        ]

        model = self.ui_item_table.model()
        model.clear()
        self.ui_item_table.setSortingEnabled(False)

        # column headers
        headers = []
        if self.ui_name_filter.isChecked():
            headers.append('Name')
        if self.ui_age_filter.isChecked():
            headers.append('Age')
        if self.ui_career_filter.isChecked():
            headers.append('Career')
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        # model.setHeaderData( i, Qt::Horizontal,thermoNames.at(i));

        # populate rows
        for x in people:

            row = []

            if self.ui_name_filter.isChecked():
                col = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                col.setData(x.get('name', 'NA'), role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                col.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                row.append(col)

            if self.ui_age_filter.isChecked():
                col = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                col.setData(x.get('age', 'NA'), role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                col.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                row.append(col)
                headers.append('Age')

            if self.ui_career_filter.isChecked():
                col = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                col.setData(x.get('career', 'NA'), role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                col.setData(x, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                row.append(col)
                headers.append('Career')

            model.appendRow(row)

        # update ui after
        self.ui_item_table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui_item_table.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = QDictTableView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter data you must use `QSortFilterProxyModel` and overwrite the `filterAcceptsRow()` method, on the other hand, creating the model every time is not elegant, you could only hide the column with `setColumnHidden()` methos of `QTableView`.

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PS_SITEPACKAGES'))
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

from functools import partial


class FilterProxy(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterProxy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters_colums = set()
        self.mText = ""

    def setText(self, text):
        self.mText = text
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def appendColumn(self, name):
        self.filters_colums.add(name.lower())
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def removeColumn(self, name):
        self.filters_colums.discard(name.lower())
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        if self.mText:
            for i in range(self.sourceModel().columnCount()):
                header = self.sourceModel().headerData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) 
                text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, i).data()
                if header in self.filters_colums and self.mText in text.lower():
                    return True
            return False
        return True


class QDictTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QDictTableView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400,300)

        # controls
        self.ui_search_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ui_search_input.setPlaceholderText('Search...')

        self.ui_item_table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.ui_item_table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_item_table.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_item_table.verticalHeader().hide()

        lay_filters = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay_main = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay_main.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_search_input)
        lay_main.addLayout(lay_filters)
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_item_table)

        model = self.populate_table()
        self.proxy = FilterProxy()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.ui_item_table.setModel(self.proxy)

        for text in ("Name", "Age", "Career"):
            checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(text)            
            checkbox.stateChanged.connect(partial(self.update_columns, text))
            checkbox.setChecked(True)
            lay_filters.addWidget(checkbox)

        self.ui_search_input.textChanged.connect(self.proxy.setText)

    def update_columns(self, text, state):
        cols = self.ui_item_table.model().columnCount()
        i = [self.ui_item_table.model().headerData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal) for i in range(cols)].index(text.lower())
        self.ui_item_table.setColumnHidden(i, state == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Unchecked:
            self.proxy.removeColumn(text)
        else:
            self.proxy.appendColumn(text)

    def populate_table(self):
        peoples = [
            {'name': 'Kevin', 'age': 5, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'Maggie', 'age': 13, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Leslie', 'age': 32, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Emily', 'age': 45, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'David', 'age': 27, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 63, 'career': 'secretary'}
        ]

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        headers = ["name", "age", "career"]
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

        for row, people in enumerate(peoples):
            items = []
            for key, value in people.items():
                col = headers.index(key)
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(value))
                items.append(item)
            model.insertRow(row, items)
        return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = QDictTableView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```